# Vue js can't display data

Tags: laravel, vue.js

My data from api I want to display is not working

```
[{"gameID":1368656,"gameReultTime":"2019-03-01 01:08:25","gameReult":2763.33,"totalPayout":1.98,"totalbet":100}]
```

display and there is no any data

```
  <tr v-for="data in dataresults">
          <td>{{data.gameID}}</td>
          <td> {{ data.totalbet }}</td>
          <td>{{data.gameReult}}</td>
          <td>{{data.totalPayout}}</td>
        </tr>
```

JS

```
data() {
return {
  dataresults: [],
};
 },

  axios
    .get("api/getoutcome")
    .then((response) => {
     this.dataresults = response.data
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.warn(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try to move your code for example to `mounted` lifecycle hook:

```
data() {
  return {
    dataresults: [],
  };
},
mounted() {
  axios
    .get("api/getoutcome")
    .then((response) => {
      this.dataresults = response.data
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.warn(error);
    });
}
```